# foreach if statement php

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a directory being generated from data in mysql.  I am looking to incorporate ads after certain categories.  Would I just put an if statement into the category foreach checking to see if a certain category matches the one I want to ad to be placed after?

```
try
    {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=YOURDB', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die;
    }

    $stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT category FROM businesses GROUP BY category');
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $categories = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($categories as $category)
    {
        echo '<h3>'.$category['category'].'</h3>';

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM businesses WHERE category = :categoryName');
        $stmt->bindParam(':categoryName', $category['category'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $businesses = $stmt->fetchAll();

        foreach ($businesses as $business)
        {
            echo $business['name'];
            echo '<br />';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that seems like the normal way to do it.

Comment: You are executing the query in the foreach loop. It is faster to gather the data in the foreach loop, and then create the query based on these values and execute the query. Limit the queries as much as possible because they are heavy for the system.

Comment: If you are willing to alter table, you can have a `show_ad` column set to `0` or `1` in `businesses` table and show the ad if `show_ad` is `1`.